# Swift layout for different orientations

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, ios-autolayout

How can I make different layouts for different orientations on ios?

I try to make an layout in landscape to show 6 picture's in 2 rows.
But in portrait I only will show 4 pictures in 2 rows.

I already have 2 different storyboard for iPad and iPhone.

Can I do this over constrains?
Can I do this with different storyboards like in android?pain[image]

Answer (score 0):

iOS has something called Size Classes. You can use a size class to target a specific device and/or orientation. You can choose the appropriate size class at the bottom of interface builder (wAny hAny) and layout your view accordingly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Nitesh's answer: Correct me if I am wrong, I am not very well versed in iOS development as well. I read that it is almost always recommended to use Size Classes  while only using one storyboard for all targeted devices. It makes handling issues like screen sizes and orientation much more managable.

In your case, may I suggest using `UICollectionView` to achieve that effect? It rearranges your tiles based on how much width you have and it supports orientation quite well.